# Program to Turn Degrees Fahrenheit to Degrees Celsius Using Defined Functions

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program in order to convert degrees Fahrenheit to degrees Celsius. The output of my code should be something like "212.0 degrees Fahrenheit = 100.0 degrees Celsius". But, when I execute my code, instead of showing a number for the degrees Celsius part, it shows 'None degrees Celsius'.

**Below is my code:**

```
Fahrenheit = float(input('Enter degrees Fahrenheit: '))


def computeCelsius():
    (Fahrenheit - 32) * (5 / 9)


celsius = computeCelsius()


def printResult():
    print(
        str(Fahrenheit) + ' degrees Fahrenheit = ' + str(celsius) +
        ' degrees Celsius ')


computeCelsius()
printResult()
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough to just *calculate* the value, you also need to return it:

```
def computeCelsius(fahren):
    return (fahren - 32) * 5 / 9
```

If a function doesn't *explicitly* return something, it will *implicitly* return `None`. You'll notice I've also passed the Fahrenheit temperature as a parameter rather than using the global variable. This is good practice, allowing you to convert *any* value or variable rather than having to load it into the global first.

You may find it useful to examine the rewrite below, using more modern Python features (like f-strings) and keeping related code close:

```
def computeCelsius(fahren):
    return (fahren - 32) * 5 / 9

fahrenheit = float(input('Enter degrees Fahrenheit: '))
celsius = computeCelsius(fahrenheit)
print(f"{fahrenheit}°F = {celsius}°C")
```

I wouldn't pass that off as your own work if this is a *classwork* assignment, but it's useful to know how a relatively seasoned Python developer could achieve the same ends with more minimalist code.